# move RAID controller + HDDs + data (RAID5) to new motherboard

Tags: motherboard, raid, hardware-raid

I have a *HighPoint RocketRAID 2300* RAID controller with 4 HDDs on my *MSI P6N SLI* mainboard and want to move the RAID controller with its HDDs and data to my new computer that has a *Asrock H61M-ITX* mainboard. I am using RAID5.

What is the recommended procedure after taking a backup of all my data?

I would simply insert the RAID controller with its HDDs, boot the OS and install the drivers. How likely is that going to work?

Comment: Which OS is installed?

Comment: None yet. I don't think it is OS dependent as long as the OS is supported by the RAID controller.

Comment: Could you provide additional details about the RAID configuration? Depending on the configuration, the drives would be marked for identification by the controller meaning that you would be able to move the array and controller to any system and have access to the array/data.

Comment: Done. I am using RAID5.

Comment: Could you please answer your question with the steps you took and mark the question as answered?

Comment: With *Done.* I meant I have provided additional details about the RAID configuration :) I still have not moved anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you bring the same controller card with you, then as far as the RAID array goes there is no problem. (If you replace the controller card with an identical one, then you may have to go into the RAID BIOS and tell it to import the RAID array.)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was thinking! I wouldn't even need to install the drivers, right? Of course if I want to do monitoring and don't want to use the RAID conrollers BIOS regularly I should install them.

Comment: Your operating system is going to need drivers, of course. Unless you just intend the drives to sit there and do nothing?

Comment: So when I boot the first time after inserting the controller card I would not be able to see or access the RAID array? This would only be possible after installing the drivers?

Comment: Right, your OS has to have drivers in order to see the RAID array. This is true of all hardware in your system.